# Read INI file section with separator to array

Tags: c#, file, csv, ini

I'm trying to convert my C++ code to Visual C#. My goal is to be able to read a INI file (not a XML file !) with some sections. Each line is assigned to a button and each button launch a command. Each INI line has 4 value, separated by a ";".

For example :

> [Button_section1]
>
> Button1=Button Scenario;open;notepad;/a;scenario.txt

Means :

- List item
- Button1 : real name of the button
- Button Scenario : the text (dipslayed name) of the button
- open : initial command (can be print or explore too...
- notepad : executable (can be any file or CMD for another example)
- /a : first argument
- scenario.txt : 2nd argument

So, in my previous code, I had 25 methods `ReadSection` and `StringSepare`, which was able to read each section of my INI file then put in array with the `StringSepare` method

When loading the form, the Button Text can be displayed from the INI file with following

```
Button bt = (Button)this.Controls.Find(i, true)[0];
```

Then clicking on the button allow to launch the following command :
(open in this case) -> notepad /a scenario.txt

NOTES :
I don't want to use any XML file, because I have a link with my SQL BD, which is interpretated as a CSV file. In fact, it is a CSV file with sections.,..

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) a .Net Ini file parser.

Answer (score 2):

I also want to plug my own ini-parser library 
https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser

You can install it with NuGet, supports Mono and it's MIT licensed, also its really easy to use

```
// Load INI file from path, Stream or TextReader.
var p = new FileIniDataParser();

// ; is also the default comment string, you need to change it
p.Parser.Configuration.CommentString = "//"; 

// Load the file
IniData parsedData = parser.LoadFile("TestIniFile.ini");

// your information
var buttonData = parsedData["Button_section1"]["Button1"].Split(new {}[";"])
```

You can access the sections and keys in the sections directly if you want to gather the data about each button:

```
foreach(SectionData section in parsedData.Sections)
    foreach(KeyData key in section.Keys)
```

Hope it is useful to you, and I accept PRs if you have any improvement  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Benji you can use my library to help you process your INI files:
https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini

For example:

```
// Set INI file's format options.
IniOptions option = new IniOptions();
// By default "CommentStarter" is ';' but you are using it as a
// multiple values separator so you need to change "CommentStarter"
option.CommentStarter = IniCommentStarter.Hash;

// Load INI file from path, Stream or TextReader.
IniFile ini = new IniFile(option);
ini.Load("Sample.ini");

// Select file's section.
IniSection sec = ini.Sections["Button_section1"];
// Select section's key.
IniKey key = sec.Keys["Button1"];
// Get key's values.
string[] values = key.Value.Split(';');
```

Also as an FYI, the library has a support for parsing multiple values (int-s, string-s, bool-s, etc.) but the syntax is different, it recognises the following:

Button1={Button Scenario,open,notepad,/a,scenario.txt}

With an above syntax you could do the following:

```
// Get key's values.
string[] values;
key.TryParseValue(out values);
```

Nevertheless I hope it's helpful to you, note that you can find additional samples in a sample projects (C# and C++/CLI) on the following link:
https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini/tree/master/MadMilkman.Ini.Samples